# Firestore security rule read permission if data meets condition

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

How to set up the security rule where the user can only read the data where it matches with the condition. for example, I have users collection and some of the users' field enabled is true and for some other it's false. I want the user to read only documents where enabled is true.

this is the security rule I have applied but I am receiving permission denied error.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {


    match /users/{user} {
        allow read: if resource.data.enabled != false;

    }

  }
}
```

Comment: What you are doing seems to be correct. Everything is forbidden, unless reading the data of a user, who has the field 'enabled' being set to false.

Comment: @Thomas I set the enabled field as true, even on all documents but still receiving the error.

Comment: Can you add the line of code you are using to access the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore Security Rules [are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters); the query restrictions should match the rules restrictions, so, for example, the query for that rule should be something like this:

```
db.collection('users').where('enabled', '==', true).get().then(/*callback*/)
```